# Add optional param to base class function, ignore in subclass

Tags: python

If I have a class hierarchy and use it like follows, including a third-party subclass that I can't change

```py
class Base:
  def doit(self):
    pass

class Sub(Base):
  def doit(self):
    print('hi')

class SubInThirdPartyLibrary(Base):
  def doit(self):
    print('hi from library')

def doit(x: Base):
  x.doit()

doit(Sub())
doit(SubInThirdPartyLibrary())
```

Is there any way I can add an optional parameter to the base class, use that in the subclass, without breaking the third-party class?

```py
class Base:
  def doit(self, msg: str = 'hi'):
    pass

class Sub(Base):
  def doit(self, msg: str = 'hi'):
    print(msg)

class SubInThirdPartyLibrary(Base):
  def doit(self):  # This isn't mine, I can't add the parameter here but want it to keep working.
    print('hi from library')

def doit(x: Base):
  x.doit(hi='hello')

doit(Sub())
doit(SubInThirdPartyLibrary())  # TypeError: doit() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

Comment: No; this is a breaking change that invalidates the previous public interface that `SubInThirdPartyLibrary` relies on.

Comment: You can overwrite `SubInThirdPartyLibrary.doit` from anywhere after the import of the module. The function has to accept a `self` argument then, just like a class's method.

Comment: `functools.singledispatch` on `doit`

Answer (score 2):

You can use `inspect.signature`:

```
import inspect

def doit(x: Base):
    sig = inspect.signature(x.doit)
    if 'msg' in sig.parameters:
        x.doit(msg='hello')
    else:
        x.doit()
```

I would recommend against doing this, and instead try another solution.